# MODX - Getresources created by logged in user

Tags: modx

- MODX Revolution 2.2.5-pl

  - getresources
  - Newspublisher

Wondering whether it is possible to show the resources that belong to the current logged in user.

The idea is to have a option in the users profile, to list of all resources created by him.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a filter of resources by `createdby` field, for example:

```
[[!getResources? 
    &parents=`[[*id]]` 
    &where=`{"createdby:=":[[!+modx.user.id]]}` 
    &tpl=`myRowTpl`
]]
```